# Is Composite Primary key require Index explicitly

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

```
select a_item_id, b_item_id from test_admin;
```

The above selected columns are composite primary key. When use `b_item_id` column in the where condition the query performing faster.
If i use `a_item_id` in the where condition the query performing very slow.

Is it required to create index explicitly for both column for composite primary key.

```
explain plan for 
SELECT A.b_item_id 
FROM child_a A,child_b B,child_c C,child_d D,child_e E
WHERE D.CDE = 1
  AND E.SUR_ID = '032'
  AND A.b_item_id = E.S_ID
  AND D.AD_ID = C.AD_ID
  AND B.PRO_ID = C.PRO_ID
  AND A.b_item_id= B.S_ID;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name        | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |             |   848 | 74624 |       |  7553   (2)|
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE                  |             |   848 | 74624 |       |  7553   (2)|
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                   |             | 12476 |  1072K|       |  7552   (2)|
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CHILD_E     |   678 | 11526 |       |   148   (0)|
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | CHILD_E_IN5 |   678 |       |       |     4   (0)|
|*  5 |    HASH JOIN                  |             | 15613 |  1082K|  1360K|  7403   (2)|
|*  6 |     HASH JOIN                 |             | 21679 |  1100K|       |  3864   (2)|
|*  7 |      HASH JOIN                |             | 21679 |   571K|       |  1830   (2)|
|   8 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL       | CHILD_A     | 21541 |   168K|       |    21   (0)|
|   9 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL       | CHILD_B     |  1832K|    33M|       |  1799   (2)|
|  10 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL        | CHILD_C     |  1700K|    40M|       |  2024   (1)|
|* 11 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         | CHILD_D     |  1224K|    22M|       |  1665   (2)|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

2 - access("A"."b_item_id"="E"."S_ID")
4 - access("E"."SUR_ID"='032')
5 - access("D"."AD_ID"="C"."AD_ID")
6 - access("B"."PRO_ID"="C"."PRO_ID")
7 - access("A"."b_item_id"="B"."S_ID")
11 - filter("D"."CDE"=1) 

Note
-----
- 'PLAN_TABLE' is old version

 31 rows selected

Elapsed: 00:00:01.513
```

Comment: What is the column definition? Is there NULLS allowed in one of the columns? Can you post the plan?

Comment: It sounds like the primary key is declared as `(b_item_id, a_item_id)`.  Add a secondary index as `(a_item_id, b_item_id)` and that should help your query.

Comment: Hi realspirituals, Both the column has NOT NULL constraint.

Answer (score 0):

it won't because to use a composite index requires using all the keys from the "left". If an index is on fields (A,B,C) and your criteria is on B and C then that index is of no use to you for that query. So choose from (a_item_id, b_item_id) and (b_item_id, a_item_id,) whichever is most appropriate for how you will use the table.

Comment: Well in fact Oracle can use the index even if the 1st indexed column is not in criteria, but it can not use `range scan` to traverse the index. Also if the size of such an index is similar to table size then  CBO will use the table directly (or it will use other index).

Answer (score 0):

If you have (b_item_id, a_item_id) included in an existing index, then queries with predicates on b_item_id or both b_item_id and a_item_id are helped.

To support queries with a predicate only on a_item_id, add an index on that column alone -- queries that would be able to use an index on b_item_id and a_item_id are already catered for.

So your two indexes would be on (b_item_id, a_item_id) and (a_item_id)